# Yoneda's lemma to prove $f^*(\tilde M) \cong \widetilde{B\otimes _A M}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $M$ be an $A$-module. and let $\phi : A \rightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphism. Let $f$ be the corresponding morphism of scheme from $SpecB$ to $Spec A$. Then prove that $f^*(\tilde M) \cong \widetilde{(B\otimes_A M)}$ , where $f^*$ is the pull back map.

I am being able to prove, $Hom_{\mathcal O_X}(f^*(\tilde M),\mathcal F)$ is bijective to $Hom_{\mathcal O_X}(\widetilde{(B \otimes _A M)} ,\mathcal F)$ for any quasi-coherent $\mathcal O _X$ module $\mathcal F$.

After this how to use Yoneda's Lemma to get the desired result.

Comment: You are done. Repeat the statement of Yoneda's Lemma.

Comment: One version is $Hom(h_X,F)$ is bijective with $F(X)$. The other version says $X\cong Y$ iff $h_X \cong h_Y $

Comment: You don't have to repeat it for me or for us, but rather for you(!), in order to see that you can apply it here. Recall (for you) what $h_X$ is, and to what $X,Y$ we want to apply Yoneda here, etc.

Comment: I was really dumb! I got it now. If we take X and Y equal to the objects respectively which we want to prove isomorphic, then we are done.